# PHP - Need the 64bit output on a 32bit php install

Tags: php, math, 64-bit, return

When I run this:

```
echo ((1 << 56) | (7 << 52) | 4437313);
```

`32bit` PHP returns:  `24360257`

`64bit` PHP returns:  `103582791433958721`

How would I go about returning the `64bit` answer on a `32bit` install of php?
I have the BC extension if that makes a difference?

Comment: Yes, the bc extension is relevant. Use that instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't know if it can be achieved with BC extension, but with [GMP](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.gmp.php) it is:

```
function gmp_shiftl($x,$n) {
    return gmp_mul($x, gmp_pow(2, $n)); 
}
$res = gmp_or(gmp_or(gmp_shiftl('1','56'), gmp_shiftl('7','52')), '4437313');
echo gmp_strval($res);
```

Comment: Thanks! - this has just saved me a big headache with backing up the VPS for a 64bit install. I'll be using this for now.  Works like a charm.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot shift more than 32 bits on a 32 bit processor.

> The size of an integer is platform-dependent, although a maximum value
>   of about two billion is the usual value (that's 32 bits signed).
>   64-bit platforms usually have a maximum value of about 9E18. PHP does
>   not support unsigned integers. Integer size can be determined using
>   the constant PHP_INT_SIZE, and maximum value using the constant
>   PHP_INT_MAX since PHP 4.4.0 and PHP 5.0.5.

http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.integer.php